# Infinite redirect with AliasMatch apache

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I'm getting infinite redirects with AliasMatch /hira/.*[^/] "/var/www/html/hira"

If anyone knows why that would be great.

Comment: This AliasMatch makes little sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: basically anything after `/hira` should just match back to `/hira` e.g. `/hira/search`, `/hira/lots/of/sub/folders` should all go back to just `/hira`

Comment: Does /hira/search (and the other URI paths you with to Alias) actually exist? If not sounds like a job for FallBackResource. if they do exist, what problem are you trying to solve, why do you need to Alias the URI paths?

Comment: @Unbeliever I'm using Angular2 and it's a requirement that I redirect back to the index.html (which is in var/www/html/hira), otherwise I'll just get page not found.

And no, /hira/search does not exist, it is merely the routing path.

Comment: You could try `FallBackResource /hira/index.html` then